# Unable to post data to database using Ionic

Tags: php, angularjs, post, service, ionic-framework

I am trying to gain some experience with creating an Ionic app. In my app, I have created a registration form.

**register.html**

```
<form ua-signup ng-controller="registerCtrl">
  <ion-view title="Sign Up">
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">ID</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.id">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.fname">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.lname">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.email" ua-is-email>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="data.pass">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Mobile No.</span>
          <input type="tel" ng-model="data.tel">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
          <div class="input-label" ng-model="data.course">
            Course
          </div>
          <select>
            <option selected>HUBIT</option>
            <option>HUBMC</option>
            <option>HUBIM</option>
            <option>HUBGM</option>
          </select>
        </label>
         <label class="item item-input">
          <div class="input-label">
            Subject
          </div>
          <select multiple="multiple">
            <option selected>HUBIT</option>
            <option>HUBMC</option>
            <option>HUBIM</option>
            <option>HUBGM</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="Register(data);">
          <span ng-show="!loading">Create Account</span>
          <i ng-show="loading" class="ion-loading-b"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
  <div class="bar bar-footer bar-assertive" ng-show="error">
  </div>
</form>
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('registerCtrl', function($scope,$http,$state) {
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.register = function(data){
          $scope.id = $scope.data.id;
          $scope.fname = $scope.data.fname;
          $scope.lname = $scope.data.lname;
          $scope.email = $scope.data.email;
          $scope.pass = $scope.data.pass;
          $scope.tel = $scope.data.tel;
          $scope.course = $scope.data.course;
          $http.post("http://localhost:81/fyp/register.php",{
            'id':$scope.id,
            'fname':$scope.fname,
            'lname':$scope.lname,
            'email':$scope.email,
            'pass':$scope.pass,
            'tel':$scope.tel,
            'course':$scope.course
          })
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("data inserted");
          })
           $state.go('tab.dash');
          }
});
```

And my **register.php** which is on a xampp server

```
?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }



$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($request->id);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($request->fname);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($request->lname);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($request->pass);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($request->email);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($request->tel);
$course = mysql_real_escape_string($request->course);

// Connect to MySQL
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
if (!$db) {
die("Could not connect to database </body></html>");
};

// open a9963146_fyp16 database
$db_select = mysql_select_db('fyp',$db);
if (!$db_select) {
die("Could not connect to database </body></html>");
};  


if($id != '' && $lname != '' & $password != '' && $email != '' && $phone != ''){
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT into Student(id, firstname, lastname, password, email, phone, course) values ('$id', '$fname', '$lname', '$password', '$email', '$phone', '$course')");
    echo "Registered successfully!";
}
else{
    echo "All fields must be filled!";
}

mysql_close( $db );
?>
```

I am still new to this and I am practicing. But I found out that the value I am trying to insert, is not added to my database. Why is it so? Did I do something wrong with codes in controller.js and the register.php? Can someone show me the mistakes I made and how can I correct it?

Comment: perhaps your ng-click function name ? Register(data) but your scope the function is register.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you start by changing the `$http.post` to the following:

```
var body = {
    'id':$scope.id,
    'fname':$scope.fname,
    'lname':$scope.lname,
    'email':$scope.email,
    'pass':$scope.pass,
    'tel':$scope.tel,
    'course':$scope.course
};

$http.post("http://localhost:81/fyp/register.php", body)
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

The reason being that the `.success` method has been deprecated for this function, as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
> deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
> $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
> methods will throw $http/legacy error.

This will probably not solve your problem, but the added error function should allow you to see whether there are any errors, which you can then share with us so we can help you further. The added variable for the body is completelyoptional.